# Bayesian error propagation: How to get probability of event given many outcomes and many realizations of process?

Tags: statistics

Imagine that a point is space **x** can be characterized by either A,B,C,D,E,F,G in the c_A, c_B .. classifications of **x** as A,B,C,... My data gives:

P(**x** = A | c_A) = f_A(**x**)

P(**x** = B | c_B) = f_B(**x**) and so on.

What I want to ask is what **x** most probably is in this realization, given the probabilities that it can be all these A,B,C... (and then marginalize out the realizations). The latter I know how to do, the former I am a bit confused as to how to formulate mathematically.

One could choose the maximum out of P(**x** = A), P(**x** = B) etc., but I would like to do it in a Bayesian way and I think what is needed for this is a proper Bayesian error propagation, I just don't understand how to do it in this context.